# Ansible Haproxy add backend with ansible

Tags: ansible, haproxy

So i would like to run a playbook via ansible on a host get the ip of that host and then add it to the haproxy.cfg.

I have managed to get the ip from the the host by using ansible_default_ipv4.address": "192.168.159.44 but i dont think this is the correct way to do this.

I want to basically add  this line
server **dnsnameofserver** **IP**:80 check fall 3 rise 2 cookie **uniquecookie**

Where the IP and DNS name is collected from the server.

So the workflow im thinking is running a playbook on a webserver and that collects the info and then it sends that information to the haproxy server.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Getting the IP from ansible facts is proper way.You can create two host groups one webserver and another haproxy server. You can then use delegate_to haproxy server to run the haproxy command.